# How to Align SlidingDrawer button on Top Right side?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am beginner to Android Application Development,currently i am working in sliding menu for both sides(left and right), i would like to align my SlidingDrawer Button on top of the Right corner.i tried many layout alignments in my code but i can't fix the problem. so anyone please guide me, Thanks in advance..
[image]
[image]

activity_main.xml

```
<com.example.lefttorightslide.Transparent
    android:id="@+id/popup_window"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:padding="30px">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Left to Right Sliding" />

    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:text="Jelly Bean" />

    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:text="Ice Cream Sandwich" />

    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:text="HoneyComb" />

</com.example.lefttorightslide.Transparent>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/handle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Handle"/>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

  <SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal"     
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
     >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Handle"
        android:gravity="top" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#00FF00">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="Right to Left" />

        <CheckBox 
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

        android:text="Jelly Bean"
        android:textSize="17dp"
            />

    <CheckBox 
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

        android:text="Ice Cream Sandwich"
        android:textSize="17dp"
            />

    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

        android:text="HoneyComb"
        android:textSize="17dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Transparent"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />

            <category android:name="q.w.e.r" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
MainActivity.java

package com.example.lefttorightslide;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
//  CheckBox cb1,cb2,cb3;
    int key=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Transparent popup = (Transparent) findViewById(R.id.popup_window);
        popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    final Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.handle);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(key==0){
                key=1;
                popup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //  btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }
            else if(key==1){
                key=0;
                popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //  btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_search);
            }
        }
    });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,Its working for me..!I have edited your code,Please try it.

```
<com.example.lefttorightslide.Transparent
    android:id="@+id/popup_window"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:padding="30px">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Left to Right Sliding" />

    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:text="Jelly Bean" />

    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:text="Ice Cream Sandwich" />

    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:text="HoneyComb" />

</com.example.lefttorightslide.Transparent>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/handle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Handle"/>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

  <SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal"     
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
     >


<RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Handle"
android:alignParentTop = "true"
        android:gravity="top" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#00FF00">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="Right to Left" />

        <CheckBox 
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

        android:text="Jelly Bean"
        android:textSize="17dp"
            />

    <CheckBox 
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

        android:text="Ice Cream Sandwich"
        android:textSize="17dp"
            />

    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

        android:text="HoneyComb"
        android:textSize="17dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```